# Manhattan distance in N-Puzzle Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I'm calculating Manhattan's distance for a N-Puzzle game. I've searched in all sites, but the proposed solution isn't good.

I'm trying this with this code:

```
def calculateManhattanDistance(matrix):
size  = len(matrix)
manhattanDistanceSum = 0
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        value = matrix[i][j]
        if(value != 0):
            targetX = (value)/size
            targetY = (value)%size
            dx = i-targetX
            dy = j-targetY
            manhattanDistanceSum = manhattanDistanceSum + abs(dx)+ abs(dy)
```

The matrix'goal is:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

If I try calculate the distance in the next matrix (the same to the goal):

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The proposed solution is 3 :S But It must be 0

I'm using this page to calculate it: [Manhattan distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770087/can-somebody-explain-in-manhattan-dstance-for-the-8-puzzle-in-java-for-me?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the solution isn't good for me.

Sorry for my regular english guys!

Comment: `calculateManhattanDistance([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])` returns 0 for me (adding `return manhattanDistanceSum` to the end of your code). Exactly what input are you giving?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it as well, it returns 0.